# Finding tokens in string for given regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like

```
`hello@{name},how are you today, location: @{location}, time: @{time}`
```

I want to find all tokens start with "@{" and ends with "}". I.e. my out put will be the list of following tokens: @{name},@{location},@{time}. or just name,location,time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
@\{(.+?)\}
```

- `@` matches a `@` character
- `\{` matches a `{`
- `\}` matches a `}`
- `.` matches everything
- `+` means to match `.` at least once, at most unlimited times
- `?` makes `+` lazy, trying as few times as possible, so the match doesn't exceed the `}`.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/wcx3Ft/1).

And you just need to get the group 1 of each match!

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("@\\{(.+?)\\}").matcher("hello@{name},how are you today, location: @{location}, time: @{time}");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

A faster but less intuitive (IMO) approach would be to replace the `.+?` part with `[^}]+`, which means "match everything that's not a `}` as many times as you can".

Comment: Rather than a dot, how about matching not `}`?  '`[^}]+`'

Comment: @Stewart Yeah, I think that would work as well. I can see that it takes less steps than a dot, but I think using a dot is more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a regex matcher with the pattern `@\{(.*?)\}`:

```
String input = "hello@{name},how are you today, location: @{location}, time: @{time}";
String pattern = "@\\{(.*?)\\}";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("match: " + m.group(1) );
}
```

**Output:**

```
match: name
match: location
match: time
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find the result, using the regular expression may be the most fast and easiest way. The java code may like this:

```
String str="hello@{name},how are you today, location: @{location}, time: @{time}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "@\\{(.*?)\\}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) );
}
```

Or you want to figure it out in you own way , you also could write some simple for loop code to solve the problem,It's good to start learning program by you hand writing your own code ,here is an example:

```
   String str="hello@{name},how are you today, location: @{location}, time: @{time}";
   String tempStr="";
   boolean inBracket=false;
   for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
          if(!inBracket) {
              if (i<str.length()-2&&str.charAt(i) == '@'&&str.charAt(i+1) == '{') {
                  inBracket=true;
                  i++;
              }
          }else{
              if(str.charAt(i)=='}'){
                  System.out.println(tempStr);
                  tempStr="";
                  inBracket=false;
              }else{
                  tempStr+=str.charAt(i);
              }
          }
      }
```

**output:**

```
name
location
time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@\{([^\}]*)\}` expression to find your tokens

Group(0) will return tokens with `@{...}`, group(1) will return only value in braces

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- create a `Pattern` defining the pattern to match
- obtain from it a `Matcher` on your string
- iterate through matches

Something like this (code written on the fly, unchecked):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

// assume that @{...} may contain only letters
// { and } symbols must be \escaped
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@\\{([a-zA-Z]+)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("hello@{name},...");
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    String x = m.group(1);   // returns "name" from "@{name}"
    // use group(0) to get the whole "@{name}"
    matches.add(x);
}
```